# Where do I get image processing using python projects. Preferablly with a code since I am a newbie and I am trying my hands on image processing

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, project

I am a newbie and would like to know a few projects
I went through various sites but couldnt find anything relevant. Need some help in getting to know where I can find computer vision assignments.

Comment: There are many hands-on tutorial here https://www.pyimagesearch.com/

Comment: The website is not working!

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please read the help section on which types of questions are on-topic here.